# Is there a way to call a non static dynamically linked member function, where the class of the member function is provided as a void*

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member, egl

Architecture: arm64
library compiled with g++.

The plugin defines and provides the type as a void* :
`typedef void *EGLSurface;`
this represents a Surface in EGL.

I would like to use a non static public member function of the Surface, and I have access to the unstripped version of the library, so I can load the function from the library  through dlsym+dlopen.
However, It's not clear to me if it is possible to call the member function using a non defined type?

Comment: How would you create an object of type `Surface` (or `EGLSurface` -- are they synonyms?)

Comment: It is provided as an argument to several of the plugins interface calls. In my case the plugin is a GLES layer, which provides a supported way to intercept opengl & egl calls